# Retornar dados de um PHP/JQUERY - Unexpected end of input

Tags: jquery

Tenho um campo chamado usuario_email, que por sua vez, ao usuário digitar o e-mail desejado, aciona o jquery para buscar no banco de dados se este e-mail já existe lá, se existir, retorna mensagem se não retorna mensagem de e-mail disponível.

Porém a única mensagem que vem no console é:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

O arquivo PHP está retornando corretamente! O problema está mesmo neste jquery.

```
<label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">E-mail de Acesso</label>
<label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">E-mail de Acesso</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario_email" name="usuario_email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail" autocomplete="off">
    <div id='resposta'></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    var email = $("#usuario_email");
        email.blur(function() {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/outras/verificaEmail.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Código do verificaEmail.php

```
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
if(isset($_POST['usuario_email'])){ 

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['usuario_email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "outrasintencoes");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuário cadastrado com este email.')); 
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Parabéns! Você poderá usar este e-mail como usuário.' )); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Podes testar `console.log(typeof data); ` na mesma linha que tens esse teu console.log? o que dá?

Comment: Retorna o mesmo erro.

Comment: Mas retorna erro antes de mostrar essa linha? qual a linha do erro? consegues localizar o código na linha de erro?

Comment: Apareceu: string, em cima do erro.

Comment: ok, podes colocar essa string aqui?

Comment: Não, apareceu apenas escrito string...

Answer (score -1):

correção:  mude de `var email = $("#usuario_email");`

para `var email = $("#usuario_email").val();`